# Version numbers for Visual Studio 2017, Boost and CMake

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, visual-studio-2017

[From the Boost mailing](http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2017/02/232814.php) list I understand that VS2017 has the following version numbers that we would probably be most interested in:

```
Visual Studio           15.0
cl; C/C++ Compiler      19.10
Platform Toolset:       v141
```

---

The following macros are defined in the Visual Studio 2017 IDE:

```
CrtSDKReferenceVersion  14.0
MSBuildToolsVersion     15.0
PlatformToolsetVersion  141
VCToolsVersion          14.10.25017
VisualStudioVersion     15.0
```

During compilation the following variables are  `#define`'d:

```
_MSC_VER                1910
_MSC_FULL_VER           191025017
```

`cl.exe` [is contained within an MSVC folder](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/07/compiler-tools-layout-in-visual-studio-15/) with the VC tools version. The complete `x64` folder path is

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64
```

`cl /Bv` from the command line lists:

```
Compiler Passes:
 cl.exe:        Version 19.10.25017.0
 c1.dll:        Version 19.10.25017.0
 c1xx.dll:      Version 19.10.25017.0
 c2.dll:        Version 19.10.25017.0
 link.exe:      Version 14.10.25017.0
 mspdb140.dll:  Version 14.10.25017.0
 1033\clui.dll: Version 19.10.25017.0
```

Notice `mspdb140.dll` and `link.exe` are listed with version 14.10.25017.0.

---

And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42271767/1460794) it seems that `msvc : 14.1` should be used as the toolset for boost. And [here is another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31885449/1460794) where some comments talk about boost's compiler naming.

When I compile I get the libraries names with v141 e.g.: `boost_atomic-vc141-mt-1_64.lib`

---

But in CMake the `_Boost_GUESS_COMPILER_PREFIX` function has the following:

```
if (NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 19.10)
  set(_boost_COMPILER "-vc150")
elseif (NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 19)
  set(_boost_COMPILER "-vc140")
```

So which version should be used? `vc141` or `vc150`? Does

- `v141` imply `vc141`, or does
- `v141` imply `vc150`?

Comment: `vc150` seems like a bug in CMake's `_Boost_GUESS_COMPILER_PREFIX` to me. What version of CMake are you using? VS2017's toolset `v141` is binary compatible with VS2015's `v140` and there is no `v(c)150` I've heard of. Probably, the developer of that CMake macro was extrapolating and guessing the toolset for VS2017.

Comment: @Torbjörn Agreed. There is a VC 15.0, but no Toolset 15.0 (yet) and the filename refers to the toolset. I'm using CMake 3.8.0-rc1.

Comment: If you are using CMake version < 3.8.0 (including an RC version) you need to use 141. If you are using CMake version > 3.8.0 you need to use 150. This issue has to do with the way Boost changed their numbering scheme.

Comment: @StAlphonzo Thanks for the update. Could you point to the Boost numbering scheme change? I don't understand why it would be 150.

Comment: I will add an answer so it formats correctly and fits in the tiny space.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In order to answer this it would be best to start with

- how Microsoft structures its products
- what Microsoft calls its products and
- how Microsoft numbers them.

So, on my system:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 has version number 15.0.26228.4. It contains:
|
+--Visual C++, informally VS, informally MSVC 
   (no version number to be found, but it is reasonable to infer 15.0) 
   which uses tools, such as
   |
   +--Toolset v141, composed of
      |
      +--compiler cl.exe version 19.10.25017.0 and
      +--linker link.exe version 14.10.25017.0 which
         |
         +--refers to CrtSDK version 14.0, and
         +--uses mspdb140.dll version 14.10.25017.0
```

It seems clear that the toolset version should be the main reference. Especially if one considers that VS 2017 can build both with `v140` and `v141`. The toolset neatly defines both the compiler and linker.

---

So then, what does it mean to compile Boost with `b2 toolset=msvc-14.0` for example? My contention is that it means toolset `v140`, not Microsoft Visual C++ `14.0`.

How would one compile with toolset `v141`? Informally msvc is usually the VS number (e.g. `15.0` for VS2017 on my system), but that would be inaccurate when specifying a toolset. Next, we note that Boost will create a file with a name containing `vcXXX` where `vc` would again seem to imply the informal notion of a Visual C++ version number such as `15.0` but certainly cannot refer to that as it is the toolset that is being specified.

So, compiling for the latest toolset on VS2017 the command would be `b2 toolset=msvc-14.1` which will generate libraries with filenames containing `vc141`. It would have been less confusing had it been `v141`, but then there would have been no reminder that we're dealing with the Microsoft toolset.

I now think of the command as follows:

```
b2 toolset=msvc-14.1
           ---- ----
             |    |
             |    +-- Toolset v141
             |
             +------- Microsoft Visual C++ (version 15.0)
```

---

Finally we can consider the CMake function in `FindBoost.cmake`. The `_boost_COMPILER` should default to `-vc141` if the compiler version is `19.10`.

Answer (score 3):

CMake versions which are less than the official release v3.8.0, which includes the rc numbers have the following in their FindBoost.cmake.

```
if (NOT CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_LESS 19.10)
  set(_boost_COMPILER "-vc150")
```

which means that, if your Boost dlls are not named like e.g. boost_date_time-**vc150**-mt-1_55.dll they won't be found. Version v3.8.0 started matching the approach Boost was taking with regard to version numbers, though I don't recall the in depth discussion of the matter. The short answer is though, if you are using a cmake version v3.8.0 or greater, you need the following instead.

```
  if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 19.10)
    set(BOOST_TOOLSET msvc-14.1)
```

For simplicity, in my Boost builds for Windows, I always add the following CMake code..

```
if(MSVC AND (NOT MSVC_VERSION LESS 1910))
  # Get the CMAKE version string and make sure it's not a release candidate and >= 3.8.0
  if( (CMAKE_VERSION MATCHES "^3\\.8\\.0-rc") OR (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 3.8.0))
    message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake 3.8.0 is the minimum version required to use Boost with Visual Studio 2017 or greater")
  endif()
endif()
```

That lets me forget about the whole issue of what the libraries should be named.