# Using boost::thread with CMake in MS Visual Studio 2017 results in two compiler errors

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, boost-thread

I want to use boost::thread in my project and I use CMake as a build tool. However, even a very simple setup results in two compiler errors:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main() 
{
    boost::thread t;
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (ThreadTest)

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF) 
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)  
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF) 
find_package(Boost 1.58.0 COMPONENTS random thread) 

set(SOURCE_DIR src)
set(SOURCE_FILES
    ${SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp
    )

if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}) 
    add_executable(test ${SOURCE_FILES})
    target_link_libraries(test ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

I'm using Boost 1.68.0 which CMake can find and is able to build proper Visual Studio project files.

I tried using boost::random, and it worked.

However, compiling the above program results in two error messages:

- **E2512**: Argument for a feature-test-macro has to be a simple identifier (pointing out to an error in boost file error_code.hpp)
- **LINK1104**: File 'libboost_thread-vc14**1**-mt-x64-1_68.lib' cannot be opened

This is the line in error_code.hpp which throws the error

[image]

I looked for the file 'libboost_thread-vc14**1**-mt-x64-1_68.lib' in my boost installation but only found 'boost_1_68_0\lib64-msvc-14.0\boost_thread-vc14**0**-mt-gd-x64-1_68.lib'

The linker settings contain the correct files:

[image]

So, my two questions:

1. Why is there a compilation error in error_code.hpp, which is part of the boost::system module and what can I do about it?
2. Why does VS want to link the file libboost_thread-vc14**1**-mt-x64-1_68.lib, instead of the correct and available libboost_thread-vc14**0**-mt-x64-1_68.lib?

Comment: It looks like you're compiling your code with a different version of your compiler than you used to build boost.  That's throwing off boost's `#pragma comment(lib, ...)` directives.  You should really build boost with the same version of your compiler you use for your code.

Comment: Since 14.0 Boost should be compatible with 14.1 toolchain, you could also disable the `#pragma comment(lib)` directives with something like `target_compile_definitions(test PUBLIC BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)`

Answer (score 7):

I get the same error message in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9 and Boost 1.69.0; I think that the trouble arises from this VS version introducing some version of __has_cpp_attribute which the boost authors expected only to be present in clang.

I had to change boost\system\detail\config.hpp line 50 
from

```
#if defined(__has_cpp_attribute)
```

to

```
#if defined(__clang__) && defined(__has_cpp_attribute)
```

as the remaining preprocessor define is only relevant to clang anyways.

Changing boost headers is quite messy, but I didn't find a clean solution yet :(.
I was hoping /Zc had some switch to deactive this new "feature" (feature testing macro)

Comment: Had the same issue with 15.9.4 and Boost 1.69.0. Your answer solves it, but I'd still love to see a solution that doesn't involve changing Boost headers.

Comment: Me too, I suspect that this must be fixed by MS or this fix has to be pushed to the boost trunk

Comment: Addenum: This is now fixed in the current develop branch; v1.70 release still has the  breaking code ( see https://github.com/boostorg/system/commit/bfbc5ec42ff35f4dcbd1547244504d4e6fc7737d )

Answer (score 1):

1) If you use

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
```

and dont give a version number for boost

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS random thread)
```

since you are using 1.68 and not 1.58, right? It should work. I can reproduce your error messages with your settings and it works using the mentioned settings.

2) The boost CMake package file searches for a boost version depending on your selected compiler, I guess the default for vs 2017 is 14.1. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42730478/version-numbers-for-visual-studio-2017-boost-and-cmake/42738533).

To solve this problem, download and install the proper prebuilt binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your hints!

The following steps resolved the problem:

1) I installed boost for MSVC 14.1 (prebuild binaries)

2) I added the following to the CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_definitions(-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB)
```

Comment: for me, the compile error did not go away with this "add_definitions"... :( What else could it be?

Comment: You have to take extra care that your Boost library exaclty matches your Visual Studio version. You should use the prebuild libraries.

Comment: @WolfgangP: The error is in a Boost header file. "Prebuilt boost libraries" affect only the .cpp files in Boost, which for prebuilt libraries will have been compiled into .obj and then linked in .lib format.